# view layout props is not working properly

Tags: react-native

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Image,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { Dialog } from "react-native-simple-dialogs";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native";
import DropdownAlert from "react-native-dropdownalert";
import { BoxShadow } from "react-native-shadow";
import { DrawerActions } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import datum from "./data";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import Parse from "parse/react-native";
import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service";
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";

const homePlace = {
  description: "Home",
  geometry: {
    location: {
      lat: 48.8152937,
      lng: 2.4597668
    }
  }
};
const workPlace = {
  description: "Work",
  geometry: {
    location: {
      lat: 48.8496818,
      lng: 2.2940881
    }
  }
};

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lat: 12.9122536,
      long: 80.0987121,
      picklat: 12.9122536,
      picklong: 80.0987121,
      droplat: 12.9202954,
      droplong: 80.1026819,
      curautostate: "pick",
      curautostateplaceholder: "Enter your pick up location",
      distance: 0,
      windowwidth: Dimensions.get("window").width,
      windowheight: Dimensions.get("window").height
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Geolocation.requestAuthorization();

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({
          lat: position.coords.latitude
        });
        this.setState({
          long: position.coords.longitude
        });

        this.setState({
          picklat: position.coords.latitude
        });
        this.setState({
          picklong: position.coords.longitude
        });

        this.setState({
          droplat: position.coords.latitude
        });
        this.setState({
          droplong: position.coords.longitude
        });
      },
      error => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Please enable the location service",
          error.message,
          [
            {
              text: "OK",
              onPress: () => console.log("has to exit")
            }
          ],
          {
            cancelable: false
          }
        );
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 10000
      }
    );
  }

  tooglestate = getstate => {
    if (getstate == "drop") {
      this.setState({
        curautostate: "drop"
      });
      this.setState({
        curautostateplaceholder: "Enter your drop location"
      });
      this.setState({
        lat: this.state.droplat,
        long: this.state.droplong
      });
    } else if (getstate == "pick") {
      this.setState({
        curautostate: "pick"
      });
      this.setState({
        curautostateplaceholder: "Enter your pick location"
      });
      this.setState({
        lat: this.state.picklat,
        long: this.state.picklong
      });
    } else {
    }
  };

  executeautocompleteView = text => {
    console.log(text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          backgroundColor: datum.secondaryColor
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#E8EDF1",
            width: "100%",
            height: "9%",
            top: 0,
            zIndex: 1,
            shadowColor: datum.secondaryColor,
            elevation: 20,
            flexDirection: "column"
          }}
        >
          <Image
            source={require("./Drawbles/Homeicon.png")}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{
              width: "10%",
              height: "100%",
              alignSelf: "center"
            }}
          />
        </View>

        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.lat,
            longitude: this.state.long,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421
          }}
          region={{
            latitude: this.state.lat,
            longitude: this.state.long,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421
          }}
        >
          <Marker
            draggable
            coordinate={{
              latitude: this.state.picklat,
              longitude: this.state.picklong
            }}
            pinColor={"#56954A"}
            onDragEnd={e => {
              this.setState({
                picklat: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
                picklong: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude,
                lat: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
                long: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
              });
            }}
          />

          <Marker
            draggable
            coordinate={{
              latitude: this.state.droplat,
              longitude: this.state.droplong
            }}
            pinColor={"#C5441B"}
            onDragEnd={e =>
              this.setState({
                droplat: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
                droplong: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude,
                lat: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
                long: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
              })
            }
          />
        </MapView>

        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            backgroundColor: datum.secondaryColor,
            zIndex: 1,
            alignSelf: "center",
            top: "10%",
            height: this.state.windowheight * 0.07,
            width: this.state.windowwidth * 0.9,
            shadowColor: datum.secondaryColor,
            elevation: 20
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.tooglestate("pick")}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: this.state.windowwidth * 0.13,
                height: this.state.windowheight * 0.07,
                backgroundColor: "#56954A"
              }}
            />{" "}
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder="Search"
            minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
            autoFocus={false}
            returnKeyType={"search"} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
            keyboardAppearance={"light"} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
            listViewDisplayed="auto" // true/false/undefined
            fetchDetails={true}
            renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
              console.log(data, details);
            }}
            getDefaultValue={() => ""}
            query={{
              // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
              key: "6Iza4Sy3APa34ewekfaM3yZB-Tt6SNO4",
              language: "en", // language of the results
              types: "(cities)" // default: 'geocode'
            }}
            styles={{
              textInputContainer: {
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: datum.primaryColor
              },
              description: {
                fontWeight: "bold"
              },
              textInput: {
                backgroundColor: datum.primaryColor
              },
              predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                color: datum.primaryColor
              }
            }}
            currentLocationLabel="Current location"
            nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
            GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={
              {
                // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
              }
            }
            GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
              // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
              rankby: "distance",
              type: "cafe"
            }}
            GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
              // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
              fields: "formatted_address"
            }}
            filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={[
              "locality",
              "administrative_area_level_3"
            ]} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
            debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
          />

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.tooglestate("drop")}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: this.state.windowwidth * 0.13,
                height: this.state.windowheight * 0.07,
                backgroundColor: "#C5441B"
              }}
            />{" "}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: datum.secondaryColor,
            width: "100%",
            height: "9%",
            top: "90%",
            zIndex: 2,
            shadowColor: datum.secondaryColor,
            elevation: 20,
            flexDirection: "row"
          }}
        />

        <DropdownAlert ref={ref => (this.dropdown = ref)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  map: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 2
  },
  headertext: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: datum.secondaryColor,

    margin: 10
  },
  bookingbar: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: "30%",
    width: "100%",
    zIndex: 30,
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

I am trying to align the Last view comp to top '90%' but somehow my layout breaks I don't know what went wrong, my black view is supposed to be at the bottom edge of the comp but it slight align up where it suppose to be, I have tried using point/and percentages but nothing seems to work, I don't where is the mistake is that with me or with react native library

[image: this the output]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the absolute position property, try this:

```
<View style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '10%',
                    top: '90%',
                    zIndex: 2,
                    shadowColor: 'black',
                    elevation: 20,
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }}/>
```